# Sending larg JSON data via UDS

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, unix-socket

I'm trying to send long json strings from one process to another via a `UDS` socket and the `UDP` protocol, like so:

```
# server.py
def main():
    if os.path.exists(UDSFILE):
        os.remove(UDSFILE)

    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(UDSFILE)

    file = open(CSVFILE, 'ab')
    msg = b''
    while True:
        while True:
            try:
                package, *_ = sock.recvfrom(4096)
                msg += package
            except ConnectionError:
                log.exception()
                raise
            if b'\t' in msg:
                data, msg = msg.split(b'\t', 1)
                break
        data = json.loads(data.decode())
        exchange, ts, data = data
        file.write(("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (exchange, ts, data)).encode())

# Client.py

def main():
    wss = GeminiWSS(args.pair)
    wss.start()

    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM)

    while True:
        try:
            sock.sendto((json.dumps(wss.get()) + '\t').encode(), socket_addr.encode())
        except Exception as e:
            log.exception(e)
            log.info("Attempting to restart..")
            wss.restart()
        except OSError as e:
            log.exception(e)
            print("OSError on connecting, trying again..")
```

The server crashes on decoding with the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scribe.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "scribe.py", line 49, in main
    data = json.loads(data.decode())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 4099 (char 4098)
```

As you can see, I've attempted to use a custom seperator to read the received data (`\t`), but this doesn't work (hence the `JSONDecodeError`).

How, then, can I make sure that my data is assembled correctly ? Unfortunately, simply ramping up the buffer isn't effective, since I don't have a maximum message length that I know of.

**Edit**
The code generating data returned from `wss.get()`:

```
def _subscription_thread(self):
    """
    Thread Method, running the connection for each endpoint.
    :param endpoint:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        conn = create_connection(self.addr + self.endpoint, timeout=5)
    except WebSocketTimeoutException:
        self._controller_q.put('restart')
        return

    while self.endpoint_thread_running:
        try:
            msg = conn.recv()
        except WebSocketTimeoutException:
            log.exception()
            raise

        log.debug("_subscription_thread(): Putting data on q..")
        try:
            self.data_q.put(('Gemini', json.loads(msg), time.time()), timeout=1)
        except TimeoutError:
            continue
        finally:
            log.debug("_subscription_thread(): Data Processed, looping back..")
    conn.close()
    log.debug("_subscription_thread(): Thread Loop Ended.")
```

**Data Samples**

The `bytes` object causing the raising of `'JSONDecodeError`:

```
b'["Gemini", {"eventId": 609771498, "events": [{"remaining": "21914.3", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.01", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "21914.3"}, {"remaining": "0.000047", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.06", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.000047"}, {"remaining": "110", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.10", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "110"}, {"remaining": "1053.33333333", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.15", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1053.33333333"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.90", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "744", "reason": "initial", "price": "1.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "744"}, {"remaining": "2400", "reason": "initial", "price": "1.10", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2400"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "5.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "8.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "0.022", "reason": "initial", "price": "9.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.022"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "11.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "30", "reason": "initial", "price": "16.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "30"}, {"remaining": "2", "reason": "initial", "price": "24.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2"}, {"remaining": "400", "reason": "initial", "price": "26.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "400"}, {"remaining": "0.03015", "reason": "initial", "price": "30.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.03015"}, {"remaining": "0.97", "reason": "initial", "price": "31.85", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.97"}, {"remaining": "0.029", "reason": "initial", "price": "33.85", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.029"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "36.97", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "2.9975", "reason": "initial", "price": "40.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2.9975"}, {"remaining": "0.04460443", "reason": "initial", "price": "67.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.04460443"}, {"remaining": "16.20200501", "reason": "initial", "price": "99.75", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "16.20200501"}, {"remaining": "62.08649948", "reason": "initial", "price": "100.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "62.08649948"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "151.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "159.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "2.60664747", "reason": "initial", "price": "191.05", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2.60664747"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "200.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "0.03976369", "reason": "initial", "price": "220.05", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.03976369"}, {"remaining": "2.6635", "reason": "initial", "price": "300.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2.6635"}, {"remaining": "0.855", "reason": "initial", "price": "350.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.855"}, {"remaining": "0.04172229", "reason": "initial", "price": "359.52", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.04172229"}, {"remaining": "0.02773771", "reason": "initial", "price": "360.52", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.02773771"}, {"remaining": "2.59220779", "reason": "initial", "price": "385.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2.59220779"}, {"remaining": "3.740625", "reason": "initial", "price": "400.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "3.740625"}, {"remaining": "1.21646341", "reason": "initial", "price": "410.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1.21646341"}, {"remaining": "1.20471014", "reason": "initial", "price": "414.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1.20471014"}, {"remai["Gemini", {"eventId": 609771500, "events": [{"remaining": "0", "reason": "cancel", "price": "2053.62", "side": "ask", "type": "change", "delta": "-2"}], "type": "update"}, 1495312354.6720355]'
```

Generated from this source:

[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YkMekRef) (moving to pastebin, due to text limit)

Comment: is `data.decode()` a valid JSON string?  Can you show us the sample data of `wss.get()` for the case where you get this error?

Comment: Well, no of course it isn't - as you can see from the traceback. `data` isn't assembled correctly. I'll add the data sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I've stopped trying to handle the UDS connecting and sending myself, and simply let python do its thing, using the `multiprocessing` library's `Client` and `Listener` classes, and supplying a file path. This now works seemlessly.

```
> listener.py
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

serv = Listener('/path/to/uds')
while True:
    conn = serv.accept()

    try:
        while True:
            msg = conn.recv()
            print(msg)
            conn.send(msg.upper())
    except EOFError:
        print('Conn closed!')
    finally:
        conn.close()  
serv.close()


> client.py
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
large_data = ''.join(['a' for i in range(1000000)])
sock = Client('/path/to/uds')
sock.send(large_data)
answer = sock.recv()
print(answer)
sock.close()
```

Not to mention that it turned out that I was splitting up the message for no reason, since UDS connections are file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with UDS but the data itself not being valid JSON string.

You error message said this:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 4099 (char 4098)
```

This means `json.loads` failed with JSON decode error because the input data is not a valid JSON string. The reason is specified as

> Expecting ':' delimiter

So you know the data is not right but where? Answer:

> line 1 column 4099 (char 4098)

Now lets get the input

```
>>> input_data = b'["Gemini", {"eventId": 609771498, "events": [{"remaining": "21914.3", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.01", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "21914.3"}, {"remaining": "0.000047", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.06", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.000047"}, {"remaining": "110", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.10", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "110"}, {"remaining": "1053.33333333", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.15", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1053.33333333"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "0.90", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "744", "reason": "initial", "price": "1.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "744"}, {"remaining": "2400", "reason": "initial", "price": "1.10", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2400"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "5.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "8.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "0.022", "reason": "initial", "price": "9.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.022"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "11.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "30", "reason": "initial", "price": "16.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "30"}, {"remaining": "2", "reason": "initial", "price": "24.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2"}, {"remaining": "400", "reason": "initial", "price": "26.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "400"}, {"remaining": "0.03015", "reason": "initial", "price": "30.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.03015"}, {"remaining": "0.97", "reason": "initial", "price": "31.85", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.97"}, {"remaining": "0.029", "reason": "initial", "price": "33.85", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.029"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "36.97", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "2.9975", "reason": "initial", "price": "40.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2.9975"}, {"remaining": "0.04460443", "reason": "initial", "price": "67.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.04460443"}, {"remaining": "16.20200501", "reason": "initial", "price": "99.75", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "16.20200501"}, {"remaining": "62.08649948", "reason": "initial", "price": "100.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "62.08649948"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "151.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "159.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "2.60664747", "reason": "initial", "price": "191.05", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2.60664747"}, {"remaining": "1", "reason": "initial", "price": "200.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1"}, {"remaining": "0.03976369", "reason": "initial", "price": "220.05", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.03976369"}, {"remaining": "2.6635", "reason": "initial", "price": "300.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2.6635"}, {"remaining": "0.855", "reason": "initial", "price": "350.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.855"}, {"remaining": "0.04172229", "reason": "initial", "price": "359.52", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.04172229"}, {"remaining": "0.02773771", "reason": "initial", "price": "360.52", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "0.02773771"}, {"remaining": "2.59220779", "reason": "initial", "price": "385.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "2.59220779"}, {"remaining": "3.740625", "reason": "initial", "price": "400.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "3.740625"}, {"remaining": "1.21646341", "reason": "initial", "price": "410.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1.21646341"}, {"remaining": "1.20471014", "reason": "initial", "price": "414.00", "side": "bid", "type": "change", "delta": "1.20471014"}, {"remai["Gemini", {"eventId": 609771500, "events": [{"remaining": "0", "reason": "cancel", "price": "2053.62", "side": "ask", "type": "change", "delta": "-2"}], "type": "update"}, 1495312354.6720355]'

>>> print(input_data[4060:4140])
b'ge", "delta": "1.20471014"}, {"remai["Gemini", {"eventId": 609771500, "events": '
```

Now its clear, your data is corrupted on this part:

> {"remai["Gemini", {"eventId"

Now you need to figure out why is your data not a valid json.

Comment: The reason It's not valid json, because somehow data gets lost when splitting it up and sending it via the uds. I've pointed that out before, so your answer is stating an obvious and stated fact.

Comment: @nlsdfnbch The data sample you included only shows what happened on the receiving end of the UDS. We also need to know what is happening on the sending end. Please include the result of printing out `wss.get()`.

Comment: The pastebin link includes the original data, packed into a tuple. But alas, not the raw string, that is true. The issue has been resolved now, either way. Thanks for the help tho!